# How to get Hibernate to ignore @OneToMany on merge?

Tags: hibernate, ejb-3.0

```
public class Application{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "application")
   private List<Licence> licences = new ArrayList<Licence>();
   ...
}

public class Licence{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false)
   private Application application;
   ...
}
```

How do I get hibernate to leave licences in application object readonly and not try to persist Licence when I go em.merge(application);

I'm not trying to save Licence with Cascade in Application. Licences have a lot business rules to run before they actually get persisted so I will be calling persist on each licence individually. How do I do this ? This works fine on persist but not on merge.

On merge I keep getting

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient 
     instance - save the transient instance before merging: com.cmr.Licence
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `insertable = false, updatable = false`. Update this

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Application application;
```

to

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Application application;
```

Comment: I think that will make the application not being saved on a licence ?
Eg: If I go em.persist(licence) I should be able to save the application and the licence. But if I go em.persist(application) I don't want the licence to get saved. adding insertable and updatable to false to application in Licence will ignore Application save on Licence which I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Its one way relation from Licence to Application. Things you need to change

1. Takeout the OneToMany relation on Application
2. On Licence Side,

   ```
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long application_id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_id")
    private Application application;

    Test:
    em.persist(application) -- should be ok. 
    em.persist(licence) - not null voilation

    licence.setApplication(application)
    em.persist(licence) - should be ok
   ```

With the above you can save Application without any Licence. But you can not save Licence without an Application. Tested, works..

-Maddy